# Identifying dimension-specific index position in R using arr.ind

Tags: arrays, r

I understand that by setting ind.arr = TRUE, R will treat the array as an array or matrix instead of a single vector. However, I am having trouble extracting elements from a multi-dimensional array.

Creating a 3x2x3 array

```
qux <- array (data = c(10, 5, 1, 4, 7, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 3, 7, 3), dim=c(3,2,3))
```

Output

```
> qux
, , 1

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10    4
[2,]    5    7
[3,]    1    4

, , 2

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    1    3

, , 3

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    7    7
[3,]    8    3
```

I would like to identify the dimension-specific index positions of elements that are either 3 OR 4. I tried to test it out by extracting elements that are 3 first and I got this as my output:

Extracting elements = 3

```
which ((qux ==3), arr.ind=T)
```

Output

```
> which ((qux ==3), arr.ind=T)
      dim1 dim2 dim3
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    1    2
[3,]    1    2    2
[4,]    3    2    2
[5,]    1    2    3
[6,]    3    2    3
```

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct. May I know how do I get the exact position (row, column and dimension if possible) of elements that are either 3/4?

**Edit**

I got this as an output after using the code

```
which((qux ==3) | (qux==4), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Output

```
       dim1 dim2 dim3
 [1,]    1    2    1
 [2,]    3    2    1
 [3,]    1    1    2
 [4,]    2    1    2
 [5,]    1    2    2
 [6,]    2    2    2
 [7,]    3    2    2
 [8,]    1    2    3
 [9,]    3    2    3
```

However, I do not understand what does all the 1s, 2s and 3s represent. Can someone explain it to me? Thank you.

Comment: `which((qux ==3) | (qux==4), arr.ind=TRUE)`

Comment: @jogo, thanks! I got this as an output but i'm not too sure what does 1,2,3 represent as shown in my edited question

Comment: For each found element you got a row in the result with the indizes of the respective element. You can use such an array for indexing `qux`, e.g. `w <- which((qux ==3) | (qux==4), arr.ind=TRUE); 
qux[w]` (o.k., for indexing in `qux` the `arr.ind=TRUE` is not needed)

Comment: The number represent the positions in the dimensions. e.g. for the first line: `1   2   1` means first row, second column, first slice (which is a 4)

Comment: Thank you @jogo & @James! :)